# Seleccionar una parte del array en base a un índice

Tags: javascript

Tengo un simple array con números `let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` y quiero cojer una "sección" de números hasta el final del array (9). La sección la decide un índice:

Por ejemplo:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
index = 3;

newArray = [7,8,9] // resultado



let array = [2,100,24,9]
index = 2;

newArray = [24,9] // resultado
```

Cuál es la manera más directa de hacerlo? Me pongo a hacer slice, splice, for loops etc y me complico tanto que me bloqueo...debe haber una manera más directa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `Array.slice()` asi:

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
index = 3;

newArray = array.slice(array.length - index, array.length) // resultado

console.log(newArray);

let array2 = [2,100,24,9]
index = 2;

newArray = array2.slice(array2.length - index, array2.length) // resultado

console.log(newArray);
```